# HTML5 charts with onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Does someone can recomend me a good (and better free) HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery... plugin
That generates charts for mobile **and can handle onClick event on chart value (very important)**
I found [humble](http://www.humblesoftware.com/) but I didn't found how to click on a value.

**The purpose:**  to click on chart value and show a popup with the point data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) charts it supports all devices and contain zoom, on click support as well
and its free too

Answer (score 0):

try amcharts.They have all sort of charts html5, javascript etc

```
http://www.amcharts.com/
```